# rough elasticity estimates of homogeneous products

Tags: regression, econometrics, regression-coefficients, elasticity

Let us say I am using a log log model to estimate the own price elasticity of a product given the unit demand data for different prices. I think this is acceptable as it is done by many practicioners.

Let us also say that I combine the price and demand data of several homogeneous products by taking the weighted average of the price using demand in units and keeping the demand in units. I then fit a log log model given this data to obtain the own price elasticities.

Would the results represent a rough estimate for the average own price elasticity of the combined product?

Thanks.